# Is it safe to shorten the RSA key to 64 bytes?

Tags: android, realm, android-keystore, android-security, realm-java

im trying to encrypt Realm DB. Key should be 64 bytes long. Minimum api level of my application is 21, so I can generate only RSA key, which minimum length is 512 bytes, relying on an android sdk solution. Is it safe to shorten the RSA key to 64 bytes?

```kotlin
KeyStoreHelper.createKeys(application, "REALM_KEY")

RealmConfiguration.Builder()
    .name("MyDatabaseName")
    .encryptionKey(KeyStoreHelper.getSigningKey("REALM_KEY")!!.take(64).toByteArray())
    .schemaVersion(2)
    .deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded()
    .build()
    .run(Realm::setDefaultConfiguration)
```

Answer (score 0):

came across this answer on [/security.stackexchange.com](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/90169/rsa-public-key-and-private-key-lengths)

TL:DR

Traditionally, the "length" of a RSA key is the length, in bits, of the modulus. When a RSA key is said to have length "2048", it really means that the modulus value lies between 22047 and 22048. Since the public and private key of a given pair share the same modulus, they also have, by definition, the same "length".A 2048-bit modulus can theoretically fit over exactly 256 bytes (since 256*8 = 2048) but you need more bytes to encode the other values.